# Keep Jupyter Notebook running on GCP

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook

I am using `Google Cloud Platform` to make a machine learning model for a problem. The dataset is huge and the model will take many hours to train.

I want to keep my notebook running and therefore keep my model training until the training is completed even though I turned off my local machine i.e my PC.

Will the notebook keep running as long as I don't turn off the instance.? Or do I want to do something else to make sure the model continues training.?

I am pretty new to GCP, thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe the notebook will keep running, but you can test it and let us know the result ;)

Comment: any specific reason why you want to use a notebook instead of a `.py` script?

Comment: Have some plotting and graphs in the notebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that the notebook won't be running if the browser is closed. I found a little trick to keep it running from [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-screen-on-an-ubuntu-cloud-server). It can be done easily with the help of a package called `screen`

Comment: `Screen` isn't bad, but I prefer `tmux`.

Comment: I will check that out

Comment: Need a step by step explanation. Possible? I am not too familiar with using ssh and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: Yes...kinda...sorta

The cell that you execute before you close your notebook will run to completion on the VM, and then it'll return it's results back to your notebook in the browser.  But since your browser is closed it won't be able to save those results back to your notebook.

Similarly, since the notebook is closed it won't be able to send the next cell to the notebook afterwards.